# Is there a way to force Socket to load cross-domain policies via HTTP?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

When connecting to a remote server, Socket tries to load cross-domain policies by sending `"<policy-file-request/>\0"` to port 843 and then to the destination port. However, some of the servers I'm working with only have their cross-domain policies located at /crossdomain.xml served over HTTP port 80.

Is there a way to force Socket to load the cross-domain policies over HTTP?

I'm aware that URLLoader will use the HTTP cross-domain policies, but it doesn't quite suit my needs.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#loadPolicyFile%28%29 However, I would suspect that you'll have to serve the crossdomain.xml file over the same port that you're trying to access.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com you should post that as the answer! I was just about to do that myself, but you beat me to it while I was looking up the url for the loadPolicyFile() method :)

Comment: I've tried this -- it doesn't authorize Socket connects. When connecting to the same server that was authorized for HTTP connections, it still tries to load the policy from port 843 and refuses to connect if it can't.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the answer is no. From [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9-10_security.html):

> **Description:** Policy files served over HTTP may no longer be used to authorize socket connections to that server. Instead, the connection must be authorized through a socket policy file. A socket policy file is a socket connection that is used to send Flash Player the XML containing the policy.